# Error in reading oracle Sql Functions in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to call the Oracle Sql functions using java. But I am getting error

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4

Can any body please help me regarding this?

Below are the statments for reading Oracle SQL Function.

```
DECLARE
  ID VARCHAR2(10);
  date1 DATE;
  output PL/SQL RECORD;
BEGIN
 ID := '1234';
  date1  := to_date('2018-05-15','yyyy-MM-dd');
  output := Function1(
    ID   => I_EMPL_ID,
    date1  => I_BALANCE_DATE
  );
END;
```

Here below is the code I used in java for calling function:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

 Date now = new java.sql.Date(simpleDateFormat.parse("17-MAY-18").getTime());

 CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call Function1(?,?,?)}");

               cstmt.setString(1, "1234");
               cstmt.setDate(2, now);
               cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ROWID);
               cstmt.execute();
```

When I execute this code, I am getting the below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: You are supposed to provide a value for the fourth `?` .

Answer (score 1):

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call Function1(?,?,?)}");
```

Has 4 `?` bind parameters.

```
                                            ^                  ^ ^ ^
                                            1                  2 3 4
```

The first is the return value from the function and the second, third and fourth are the arguments to the function.

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.ROWID );
cstmt.setString( 2, "1234" );
cstmt.setDate(   3, now );
cstmt.setInteger(4, 0 );       // Or whatever type the 3rd function argument has.
cstmt.execute();
```